# Metadata Type to Folder Structure

Tags: metadata, package.xml

Is there a list of Metadata types to the src folder structure (folder names)?

For example in package.xml Apex Classes are

```
<Name>ApexClass</Name>
```

But are actually found in the directory

```
src/classes/
```

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm) list all the Package.xml type names, but I don't see any documentation of the folder structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [describeMetadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_describe.htm?search_text=describemetadata) call to learn the folder names of each of the types. A Java sample is included:

```
public void describeMetadata() {
  try {
    double apiVersion = 21.0;
    // Assuming that the SOAP binding has already been established.
    DescribeMetadataResult res =
        metadataConnection.describeMetadata(apiVersion);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    if (res != null && res.getMetadataObjects().length > 0) {
      for (DescribeMetadataObject obj : res.getMetadataObjects()) {
        sb.append("***************************************************\n");
        sb.append("XMLName: " + obj.getXmlName() + "\n");
        sb.append("DirName: " + obj.getDirectoryName() + "\n");
        sb.append("Suffix: " + obj.getSuffix() + "\n");
        sb.append("***************************************************\n");
      }
    } else {
      sb.append("Failed to obtain metadata types.");
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
  } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
    ce.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The Migration Toolkit includes a [describeMetadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_describemetadata.htm) task that essentially uses this same code.

The documentation only describes the folder names in each element. For example, starting from [Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm), you can click on [ApexClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_classes.htm), which tells us:

> ## Declarative Metadata File Suffix and Directory Location
>
> The file
> suffix is .cls for the class file. The accompanying metadata file is
> named ClassName-meta.xml.
>
> Apex classes are stored in the classes folder in the corresponding
> package directory.

Comment: I would say the "just find them in the documentation" bit is the bigger revelation here.

Comment: @sfdcfox That will only get the Metadata of active features in an org. IE since I don't have Live Agent in my org (yet) the Live Agent Metadata types are not returned. Ideally I would like a map of every metadata type listed in the documentation.

Comment: Wew, I completely missed that the folder is listed in the Metadata Type details screen. To bad it's not in a consistent format. For example "LiveAgentSettings values are stored in the LiveAgent.settings file in the settings directory" as opposed to "Apex classes are stored in the classes folder"

Comment: @Stephen I mentioned both ways because either might be applicable. For example, if you're creating a tool that works with metadata, like the Force.com IDE, being able to describe all the elements makes sense. Contrariwise, if you need *everything*, the documentation is where you need to go. I think the real crime is they don't have a page that lists each type, the folder, and the file extension/metadata file extension.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yeah, ideally that is what I would be able to get from them. I'll have to compile myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Of those I use most commonly:

```
type                path
ApexClass           /src/classes
ApexComponent       /src/components
ApexPage            /src/pages
ApexTrigger         /src/triggers
CustomLabel         /src/labels
StaticResource      /src/staticresources
```

The rest can be found in the documentation, [as noted by](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140076/metadata-type-to-folder-structure/140081#140081) [@sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox).

Comment: Just use the migration toolkit to get the list.